# GHUnit: HTTPS REST tests are always failing on CLI

Tags: http, https, command-line-interface, gh-unit

I'm doing a project where I must to do iOS apps auto-testing, and all that iOS apps have GHUnit as testing Framework.

This apps have some REST HTTP and HTTPS tests that give us expected results if we run that tests on the iOS devices or iOS simulator.

But when we run the tests through CLI, all the HTTPS tests fail (all of them).

If we change that HTTPS services to HTTP, they give us the expected results (all OK)

The tests do the REST call on a HTTP domain, but then it redirect us (301 HTTP code) to an HTTPS service.

So here is my question: is it a bug, or is an unimplemented feature?. Could CLI GHUnit handle HTTPS connections?. Anyone has any HTTPS REST test working with GHUnit on CLI?

Answer (score 0):

When the tests are launched from the command line the simulator keychain is not available. A ticket is open in the project and a patch is available as a [pull request](https://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit/pull/83) (but not merged at the time I write these lines).